# Would come vs will come

Tags: modality

I'm not sure but I think the following sentences are related to the certainty or uncertainty of the fact that he will come or not.Or I think would come indicates some kind of uncertainty than will come.so, If the speaker were certain he would use 'will'. for examples :

1.Do you think he'd come? | I'm sure he would. (Here the speaker isn't sure that he will come)shows uncertainty

2. Do you think he will come? | I'm sure he will. (Here the speaker is sure that he will come ) shows certainity

Am i right here in my opinion?

If first sentence indicates uncertainity( if my openion is correct), But why there is the use of 'would' with 'sure' in first sentence?

context: is there the 'if clause' hidden in those sentences? What about if I already invited him(Tom) at my home and he haven't come yet to my home and i'm talking with one of my friend Ram about weather Tom will come or not.

Comment: There is no way to answer "why there is the use of 'would' with 'sure' in first sentence?" without knowing the context. Of whom is the speaker asking the question, and to whom? If, for instance, question 1 is preceded by "If I gave a party...," then the answer "I'm sure he would" is a perfectly natural response.

Comment: @yubrajshama It is very distracting when you misuse punctuation. **Punctuation is as important as grammar.** "..come or not.Or I think .." is wrong. "...uncertainity( if my openion..." is wrong. "than will come.so, If the speaker ..." is wrong twice because we capitalize the first word of a sentence in English. Can you see all these errors?

Comment: @P E dent,I'm using mobile so I can't see those error.on the other hand,Do you mean there's the 'if clause' hidden in those sentences?context is : What about if I already invited him(Tom) at my home and he haven't come yet and i'm talking with one of my friend Ram about weather Tom will come or not?

Comment: Do you mean that your mobile device renders the comma and the period invisible? Please look at the comment you just made and tell me if you notice anything unusual about the punctuation.

Comment: @pE dent, yes it renders a bit But I can also see errors. There full stop, punctuation and space errors.I'm using mobile data.so,I'm not using stackoverflow app which enables me to correct mistakes.That's why I can't correct them.